# How to pass String as Into<Str> argument when using Clap?

Tags: rust, clap

I am trying to use [clap](https://crates.io/crates/clap) to create a CLI application. A `Command` has a [constructor](https://docs.rs/clap/4.4.18/clap/struct.Command.html#method.new) like this:

```
impl Command {
    pub fn new(name: impl Into<Str>) -> Self {...}
}
```

But I need to pass there a name loaded from shared `.so` library. The only way I can use it is something like:

```
let mut registry = Registry::new();
registry.load("./libapp_addon_no1.so").ok();
registry.load("./libapp_addon_no2.so").ok();

for command in registry.commands() {
    // command.name is a String
    cli = cli.subcommand(Command::new(&*command.name.clone().leak()));
}
```

It works, but is there a better way to produce `Into<Str>` from a copy of `String`?

Comment: Looks like you'll need a feature to enable `From<String>` here: https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/builder/struct.Str.html#impl-From%3CString%3E-for-Str

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`Str`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/builder/struct.Str.html):

> **NOTE:** To support dynamic values (i.e. `String`), enable the `string` feature

You can use cargo to add the `string` feature:

```
cargo add clap -F string
```

Or you can edit Cargo.toml manually:

```ini
[dependencies]
clap = { version = "4.4.18", features = ["string"] }
```